How to extract text from an element using bs4
I am scraping Airbnb (Link to the following page), and one of the things I want to get is since when is the host hosting, as shown in the picture below (marked with red pen):
image example
The code I am currently using to solve this is:
account_active_since = soup.find('li', class_='l7n4lsf atm_9s_1o8liyq_keqd55 dir dir-ltr').getText()

but with this code I get the following output:
3 guestsStudio1 bed1 bath

The HTML tag for it is:
<div class="s1l7gi0l atm_c8_km0zk7 atm_g3_18khvle atm_fr_1m9t47k atm_7l_1esdqks dir dir-ltr"><ol class="lgx66tx atm_gi_idpfg4 atm_l8_idpfg4 dir dir-ltr"><li class="l7n4lsf atm_9s_1o8liyq_keqd55 dir dir-ltr">3 years hosting</li></ol></div>

HTML
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.
Here is the whole code. The part of the code that needs fixing is in line 77 (in the for loop):
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time
import re

URL = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/San-Francisco--California--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2024-06-01&monthly_length=3&monthly_end_date=2024-09-01&price_filter_input_type=0&channel=EXPLORE&query=San%20Francisco%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States&place_id=ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo&date_picker_type=calendar&checkin=2024-05-08&checkout=2024-05-22&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(4)

try:
    accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-application"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/section/div[2]/div[2]/button')
    accept_cookies.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No 'Accept cookies' found.")

elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='site-content']//div[@data-testid='card-container']//div[@class = ' dir dir-ltr']//a[1]")

while True:
    try:
        for element in elements:
            try:
                element.click()
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                print("No more elements to click.")
                break

            # Switch to the newly opened tab
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

            time.sleep(4)

            page_source = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

            try:
                close_pop_up = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                   '/html/body/div[9]/div/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button')
                close_pop_up.click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("No pop up element found.")

            try:
                apartment_name = soup.find('h1', class_='hpipapi').getText()
            except AttributeError:
                apartment_name = "Name not specified"

            try:
                short_description = soup.find('h2', class_='hpipapi').getText()
            except AttributeError:
                short_description = "Description not specifed"

            try:
                rooms_bathrooms = soup.find('div', class_='o1kjrihn').getText()
            except AttributeError:
                rooms_bathrooms = "Utilities not specified"

            try:
                price_per_night = soup.find('span', class_='_1y74zjx').getText()
            except AttributeError:
                price_per_night = "Price not specified"

            try:
                host_name = soup.find('div', class_='cm0tib6').find('div', class_='t1pxe1a4').getText()
            except (AttributeError, IndexError):
                host_name = "Host name not specified"

            # This variable needs to be fixed
            try:
                account_active_since = soup.find('li', class_='l7n4lsf atm_9s_1o8liyq_keqd55 dir dir-ltr').getText()
            except AttributeError:
                account_active_since = "Active since not specified"

            try:
                guest_favourite_stars = soup.find('div', class_='a8jhwcl').getText()
                guest_favourite_stars = re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', guest_favourite_stars).group()
            except AttributeError:
                guest_favourite_stars = "Not guest favourite"

            try:
                guest_favourite_reviews = soup.find('div', class_='r16onr0j').getText()
            except AttributeError:
                guest_favourite_reviews = "Not guest favourite"

            print("Apartment Name:", apartment_name)
            print("Short Description:", short_description)
            print("Rooms and Bathrooms:", rooms_bathrooms)
            print("Price per Night:", price_per_night)
            print("Host Name:", host_name)
            print("Account Active Since:", account_active_since)
            print("Guest favourite stars:", guest_favourite_stars)
            print("Guest favourite reviews:", guest_favourite_reviews)

            time.sleep(1)

            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, 100);")

            driver.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{apartment_name.replace(" ", "_")}.png')

            # Close the current tab
            driver.close()

            time.sleep(1)

            # Switch back to the main tab
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No more elements to click. Heading to the next page.")

    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="site-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/nav/div/a[5]')
        next_page.click()
        time.sleep(2)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No more pages to click.")
        break

    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='site-content']//div[@data-testid='card-container']//div[@class = ' dir dir-ltr']//a[1]")

driver.quit()


It is impossible to tell what is wrong without seeing the actual HTML that you are dealing with.

Chances are that the AirBnB page is rendered with JavaScript and, if that's the case, you won't get reliable results with BeautifulSoup. Try selenium

I am using selenium to open the page.

@OldBoy I have posted the actual HTML, and there is a link to the page.

Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!!! I was wondering if you could provide us with the code you have to access the webpage with Selenium. Maybe the issue is over there (though I don't think so, since you currently get an output, but its worth the try).

@anmabe I have added the whole code. The part of the code that needs fixing is in line 77 (in the for loop).

I have just looked at the raw HTML and cannot find either the string "l7n4lsf atm_9s_1o8liyq_keqd55" or "3 years hosting".  How did you find that class name?

I have added a screenshot from the site under the image name HTML.

Here is one way of getting that information (no BeautifulSoup needed):
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as browser:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)

    url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/46181703?check_in=2024-05-08&check_out=2024-05-22&source_impression_id=p3_1714848136_vsUX6ezsi0Z7N%2FSG&previous_page_section_name=1000&federated_search_id=efebfc50-8682-44ac-acee-e5d374cb3da4'
    browser.get(url) 
    hosting_since = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-section-id="HOST_OVERVIEW_DEFAULT"]//li[contains(text(), "hosting")]'))).text
    print(hosting_since)

Result in terminal:
3 years hosting

Selenium documentation can be found here.
